# IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

Here is my script of my db ,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Code] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[dob] [date] NULL ,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
[ID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I insert , I got this error

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MyTable' when   
IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a column is defined as IDENTITY you should not include it in the insert statement 
SQL Server by it self will insert the value.

```
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE([CODE],[NAME],[DOB]) VALUES (123,'BOND','01-04-1971')
```

If you look at the insert statement ID column is missing but still will get a incremented value upon executing this statement.

Answer (score 1):

See tictac's response. Or you can manually insert any unique identity value you want, by first executing the command:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
```

Then run your script, followed by

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF
```

Comment: You'll also want some error handling here. E.g. if you try to insert a duplicate value for ID you'll get a primary key violation, which may prevent the SET OFF command from running... it's session-based, but still not tidy.

Comment: True that. But then, most any operation usually requires some manual error / transaction handling, which depending on circumstances I believe should usually be rather obvious to the one creating and delivering the script. :) But yes, a good point in that SQL Server actually prohibits the latter SET command, meaning any following SET ON's within the same script and session would fail.